# I want to group by date, but how can I do it in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

The data type is as follows.

```
_id: ObjectId
details: array
     0: Object
        salesManagerId: ObjectId
createdAt: Date
```

The data type is as follows.

What I want is,

- Date: Group by date. Sorts in descending order through the results grouped by year, month, and day. As a sorted result, it should be sorted in the same order as 20211020, 20211019 .
- Sales: It should be output how many _ids are included by date grouped by date. I think it's equivalent to SELECT COUNT(*) in mysql.
- Own Sales Volume: Among the grouped counts, the number including details should be output. However, if specific obejctId is included in details.salesManagerId, it should be excluded.

I expect below table.

```
Date       Sales    Own Sales Volume
20211020   30       11
20211019   15        2
20211018   23        3
.
.
.
```

In particular, I am having a hard time grouping by date.

Comment: You can use an Aggregation query with `$group` stage - where you can specify the field to group by. With grouping you can do aggregations like count, total, max, min, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$group`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        year: {
          $year: "$createdAt"
        },
        month: {
          $month: "$createdAt"
        },
        day: {
          $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
        }
      },
      "Sales": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "Own Sales Volume": {
        "$sum": {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $isArray: "$details"
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      "$size": "$details"
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wz4tH9VN1NJ)

Comment: thx your answer. `details` may or may not be present. For example, in the attached table, 20211020 `sales` is 30, but `Own Sales Volume` is 11. What this means is that 19 out of 30 contain `details` and 8 contain multiple specific `details.salesManagerId`s, so the result is 11.

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: What is the code except for details.salesManagerId in the code above? I think $nin operator. for example $match: {"details.salesManagerId": {$nin: [ObjectId()...ObjectId()...]}}

Comment: Edit your question with a full test data to present your problem. Then I can modify my answer and check by your test data whether I'm right or not. Or accept my answer and ask another question.

Comment: With MongoDB 5.0 you can also group by `{ _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$createdAt", unit: "day" } }`

Comment: @YuTing could you check my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735674/how-can-i-exclude-results-that-contain-a-specific-element-from-grouped-results